# 'Public Event PropertyChanged is event and cannot be called directly Use aRaiseEvent

Tags: vb.net

> Here where I  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged


    Private Function RaisePropertyChanged() As Action(Of PropertyChangedEventArgs)
       Return Function(args)   IIf(PropertyChanged.Invoke, Me, args)
    End Function
```

Comment: `RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(args))`.... see if that helps you. No need for a function, if you want something use a method... `Private Sub RaisePropertyChanged(args)
       RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(args))
    End Sub`

Comment: Whats the point of that `IIF` statement *after* the return?